# How to define Map as argument in angular TypeScript method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would need some help, because I am stuck. I have problems defining a simple method in angular4 (TypeScript) that gets an argument of the type Map. All I want is to iterate over the elements in the `Map`. Nothing special.

When I try to iterate over the Map object `map2` I get the following error.

Error: `ERROR TypeError: map2.forEach is not a function`

```
doStuff(map2: Map<string, string>):number{
  //I get an ERROR here, because map2 is not recognised as a Map()?
  map2.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
  console.log(key, value);  
  });

  let map = new Map();
  map.set("A","B");
  map.set("C","d");

  console.log(map.get("A")+" :"+ map.size);
  //THIS WORKS
  map.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
  console.log(key, value);
   });
    }
});
```

This is how I call the method from another method

```
...
//some other method
let map4 = JSON.parse('{ "myString": "string", "myNumber": "4" }');
this.myNumber = this.doStuff(map4);
...
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? What are you passing to it?

Comment: Your call to `JSON.parse` returns an anonymous object; it does not return a `Map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert a literal object (that is returned by `JSON.parse`) into a `Map` to pass it to `doStuff`. You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (available from ES2017) for that:

```
let map4 = JSON.parse('{ "myString": "string", "myNumber": "4" }');
this.myNumber = this.doStuff(new Map(Object.entries(map4)));
```